# Does Promise.all() in bluebird wait for the iterator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

In the case of the following example from http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

```
var files = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    files.push(fs.writeFileAsync("file-" + i + ".txt", "", "utf-8"));
}
Promise.all(files).then(function() {
    console.log("all the files were created");
});
```

Is it ensured by (bluebird) Promise that the for loop would finish before we start the `Promise.all()` line or are the for loops so fast that we can assume they will finish before `Promise.all()` line?

I'm trying to understand what I  can expect to be finished in order, and what I need to wrap around Promise, so that I don't write something like this when unnecessary:

```
some_promise_that_makes_files_array_with_for_loop().then(function(files){
    Promise.all(files).then(function() {
        console.log("all the files were created");
    });
});
```

Comment: The `for` loop is synchronous, so it's guaranteed by javascript being single threaded that it most definitely will finish before the next line of code, regardless of what that is.

Comment: This would be trivial to do without bluebird as well -> https://jsfiddle.net/dy3cmart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will wait, assuming that `fs.writeFileAsync()` returns a promise (I can't tell which fs library this is from because NodeJS doesn't have a `writeFileAsync()` method).

The for loop is synchronous, so it must complete before the `Promise.all()` is called. It starts a bunch of asynchronous calls, but it immediately populates the `files` array with one promise per call.

Those promises will resolve themselves in whatever order the file writes complete. At which point, your `all promise` will call it's `.then()` method.

Comment: the `Async` suffix looks like it's the result of a bluebird `Promsie.promisifyAll` - so it's a pretty good bet that it returns a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, this is a feature of Bluebird. [All promisified functions receive the suffix `Async`.](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html)

Comment: @peteb - actually that's not exactly true - you can [set your own suffix](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html#option-suffix)

Comment: Okay, so either way, it's a Bluebird thing doing some promise wrapping. Good to know, but I'm not sure I should add that to the answer specifically.

Comment: Is there a rule or a list to find out what kind of things run synchronously? I.E. where does one look to find which one of these will run synchronously: creating new instances of objects, setting a property of an object, any called method of an object, requiring a js script. (What kind of tests can be done to find it on our own? What kind of setup would create a test environment for figuring out what is synchronous?)

Comment: @Logan that should be a completely new question on SO

Comment: @Soviut Yeah I agree. I have just realized it